# Arrange PHP array in ascending order by its value, preserving key associations

Tags: php, arrays

How can I arrange my array to ascending order looking on its value?
This is my array:

```
array(4){
    ["id"]=>
      int(3)
    ["batch_code"]=>
      int(4)
    ["date"]=>
      int(2)
    ["name"]=>
      int(1)
}
```

I'm expecting the result to be:

```
array(4){
    ["name"]=>
      int(1)
    ["date"]=>
      int(2)
    ["id"]=>
      int(3)
    ["batch_code"]=>
      int(4)
}
```

Comment: @tim Thanks. I will update my question for my main scenario :)

Comment: @Phil I have updated my question to my main situation, my problem is that they don't have the same keys always, and how can I arrange it in ascending order?

Comment: @Phil I apologize for I really don't know where to start. Thanks.

Comment: You want [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/function.asort.php)

Comment: @Phil `asort` does the trick. Thanks and apologies for the inconvenience caused :)